# How to switch output from task to task

Tags: javascript, gulp, eslint, gulp-eslint

Is it possible to switch Gulp's output between tasks?

For example, I'd like to run my `build` task continuously and see its output by default, and I want to be able to replace `build`'s output with `eslint`'s output, but only if such occurs. So, I can see `build`'s output again, if all offences are corrected.

Seemed pretty straightforward before I started to tinker. Am I missing something?

Comment: could you provide the implementation of your task? Please post your gulpfile

Comment: @TomM honestly I don't think it'd be much of help. Basically it has two tasks (one is system call made with spawn) and me staring on them

Comment: Anyways https://gist.github.com/askhat/95ca048ae0a3f2942beb4ad55810c9d4

Comment: What is spawn? What it does? I dont get your question, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Not a proper solution. But here's an idea.

```
var originalStdoutWrite = process.stdout.write;
process.stdout.write = function(){ return; }
gulp.src(['**/*.js','!node_modules/**'])
    .pipe(eslint())
    .pipe(eslint.results(results => {
        // Called once for all ESLint results.
        if(results.errorCount>0){
            originalStdoutWrite.call(process.stdout,`Total Results: ${results.length}`);
        }else{
            process.stdout.write = originalStdoutWrite;
        }
    }));
```